# cannot subscript a value of type '[item]' with an index of type 'item'

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I'm trying to loop trough an array within a JSON struct, but whatever I do i'm getting the error "Cannot subscript a value of type '[item]' with an index of type 'item'. I can print it whenever I call upon each index separately:

```
self.socialTitle = (storeSocialContext.items?[1].metatags?.first?.title)!
print(self.socialTitle)
```

Which gives me back a string, how i want it. But I want the strings of each index, for the title.
This is the loop which gives the error:

```
 var anArray = storeSocialContext.items!

                for socialIndex in anArray {
                    if anArray[socialIndex] != nil {

                    }

                }
```

And this is the struct:

```
struct StoreSocialContext: Decodable
{
    var items: [Item]?
}

struct Item: Decodable
{
    var metatags: [enclosedTags]?

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey
    {
        case pagemap
    }

    enum PageMapKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case metatags
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let pagemap = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: PageMapKeys.self, forKey: .pagemap)
        metatags = try pagemap.decode([enclosedTags].self, forKey: .metatags)
    }
}

struct enclosedTags: Decodable
{
    let image: String?
    let title: String?
    let description: String?
    let siteName: String?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey
    {
        case image = "og:image", title = "og:title", description = "og:description", siteName = "og:site_name"
    }
}
```

And this is a snipped of the data whenever I fetch and print the JSONdata in the console:

```
Optional([GetContext.Item(metatags: Optional([GetContext.enclosedTags(image: 
nil, title: nil, description: nil, siteName: nil)])), GetContext.Item(metatags: 
Optional([GetContext.enclosedTags(image: Optional("https://www.merriam- 
webster.com/assets/mw/static/social-media-share/mw-logo-245x245@1x.png"), 
title: Optional("Definition of BEST"), description: Optional("excelling all 
others; most productive of good : offering or producing the greatest advantage, 
utility, or satisfaction; most, largest… See the full definition"), siteName: 
nil)])), ...])
```

Comment: What is `socialTry`? Why is your array of `Item` assigned to a variable named `socialItem` instead of `socialItems`? In your `for` loop, why is a single `Item` assigned to a variable named `socialIndex`? Better variable naming will make your code much easier to read and it will make your issues easier to solve.

Comment: Tnx, I edited it. I messed up the variables while typing up the question. Hope it's more clear now. Let me know if not.

Comment: A for-in loop iterates over the items in the array, not the index.  So unless you need the index itself for something, you already have your item and don't need to subscript anything. See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html

Comment: Apart from the issue the `nil` check is pointless. The array doesn't contain any optionals.

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
for socialIndex in anArray {
    if anArray[socialIndex] != nil {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Doesn't make any sense.

If you have a type `Thing`, and an array

```
var array: [Thing] = [thing1, thing2, thing3]
```

and you use the code `for thing in array { //your code here }`

then the variable `thing` contains elements of your array, and is of the type `Thing`

In your code `for socialIndex in anArray` your variable `socialIndex` will contain elements from your array, and be of the type of those array elements.

Thus the bit where you try to index into anArray: `anArray[socialIndex]` is not valid.

You need to index into the array using Int indexes, and you've already extracted an element from the array, so there's no point.

This code:

```
let strings: [String?] = ["now", "is", "the", nil, "time"]

for string in strings {
   if let aString = string {
       print(aString)
   }
}
```

Will output

`now
is
the
time`

And the code:

```
for string in strings {
   if strings[string] != nil { //This makes no sense. `string` is of type String
   }
}
```

Doesn't make sense.